# suppress database error messages when SET NOEXEC ON is used

Tags: t-sql

Here is a sample script that mimics an issue that has surfaced in a more complex script being written for Prod -

```
SET NOEXEC ON;
PRINT 'This statement will not print.';
GO
SELECT [FakeColumn] FROM sys.objects;
DECLARE @T INT = NEWID();
GO
SET NOEXEC OFF;
/*
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line XX
Invalid column name 'FakeColumn'.
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line XX
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int
*/
```

The question is, how can the error messages be suppressed?

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://XY problem.info). Though, if you *really* don't care about an error then just don't `THROW` it in a `TRY...CATCH`; but the is just as bad as the old `On Error Resume Next` syntax in VB.

Comment: The URL provided didn't work.  Would you mind reposting it?

Comment: Just remove the space; autoincorrect was being as unhelpful as always.

Comment: You cannot suppress invalid query with SET NOEXEC ON (it doesnt execute, but want compile). You can envelope your query with EXEC statement which will prevent compilation.